# Adding payment details to Stripe API charge call

Tags: vue.js, stripe-payments

While creating a Stripe payment I cannot seem to get the values from the rest of the form with Stripe? I have searched the docs and cannot find what they are looking for in the html to pull the form data. When I `console.log` the information that is pulled from the form I see `null` values across all of the variables.

This is a Vue application.

[image]

HTML

```
<template>
  <form method="post" id="payment-form">
    <h4 class="h4Spacing">Billing Information</h4>
    <div class="form-group">
      <b-form-input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email Address"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <b-form-input  type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name on Card"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <b-form-input type="text" class="form-control" id="address_line1" name="address_line1" placeholder="Address"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <b-form-input type="text" class="form-control" id="address_city" name="address_city" placeholder="City"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <b-form-input type="text" class="form-control" id="state" name="state" placeholder="State"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div id="card-element" class="form-control">
        <!-- A Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
      </div>
      <div v-if="successful">
        <h3 class="title" data-tid="elements_examples.success.title">Payment successful</h3>
        <p class="message"><span data-tid="elements_examples.success.message">Thanks for trying Stripe Elements. No money was charged, but we generated a token: </span><span class="token">tok_189gMN2eZvKYlo2CwTBv9KKh</span></p>
        <a class="reset" href="#">
          <svg width="32px" height="32px" viewBox="0 0 32 32" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
            <path fill="#000000" d="M15,7.05492878 C10.5000495,7.55237307 7,11.3674463 7,16 C7,20.9705627 11.0294373,25 16,25 C20.9705627,25 25,20.9705627 25,16 C25,15.3627484 24.4834055,14.8461538 23.8461538,14.8461538 C23.2089022,14.8461538 22.6923077,15.3627484 22.6923077,16 C22.6923077,19.6960595 19.6960595,22.6923077 16,22.6923077 C12.3039405,22.6923077 9.30769231,19.6960595 9.30769231,16 C9.30769231,12.3039405 12.3039405,9.30769231 16,9.30769231 L16,12.0841673 C16,12.1800431 16.0275652,12.2738974 16.0794108,12.354546 C16.2287368,12.5868311 16.5380938,12.6540826 16.7703788,12.5047565 L22.3457501,8.92058924 L22.3457501,8.92058924 C22.4060014,8.88185624 22.4572275,8.83063012 22.4959605,8.7703788 C22.6452866,8.53809377 22.5780351,8.22873685 22.3457501,8.07941076 L22.3457501,8.07941076 L16.7703788,4.49524351 C16.6897301,4.44339794 16.5958758,4.41583275 16.5,4.41583275 C16.2238576,4.41583275 16,4.63969037 16,4.91583275 L16,7 L15,7 L15,7.05492878 Z M16,32 C7.163444,32 0,24.836556 0,16 C0,7.163444 7.163444,0 16,0 C24.836556,0 32,7.163444 32,16 C32,24.836556 24.836556,32 16,32 Z"></path>
          </svg>
        </a>
        <div class="caption">
          <span data-tid="elements_examples.caption.no_charge" class="no-charge">Your card won't be charged</span>
          <a class="source" href="https://github.com/stripe/elements-examples/#example-1">
            <svg width="16px" height="10px" viewBox="0 0 16 10" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
              <path d="M1,8 L12,8 C12.5522847,8 13,8.44771525 13,9 C13,9.55228475 12.5522847,10 12,10 L1,10 C0.44771525,10 6.76353751e-17,9.55228475 0,9 C-6.76353751e-17,8.44771525 0.44771525,8 1,8 L1,8 Z M1,4 L8,4 C8.55228475,4 9,4.44771525 9,5 C9,5.55228475 8.55228475,6 8,6 L1,6 C0.44771525,6 6.76353751e-17,5.55228475 0,5 C-6.76353751e-17,4.44771525 0.44771525,4 1,4 L1,4 Z M1,0 L15,0 C15.5522847,-1.01453063e-16 16,0.44771525 16,1 L16,1 C16,1.55228475 15.5522847,2 15,2 L1,2 C0.44771525,2 6.76353751e-17,1.55228475 0,1 L0,1 L0,1 C-6.76353751e-17,0.44771525 0.44771525,1.01453063e-16 1,0 L1,0 Z" fill="#AAB7C4"></path>
            </svg>
            <span data-tid="elements_examples.caption.view_source">View source on GitHub</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>

      </div>



  <!--  <form action="/charge" method="post" id="payment-form">-->
<!--    <div class="form-row">-->
<!--      <label for="name"> Name </label>-->
<!--      <div id="name"></div>-->



<!--      <label for="card-element">-->
<!--        Credit or debit card-->
<!--      </label>-->
<!--      <div id="card-element">-->
<!--        &lt;!&ndash; A Stripe Element will be inserted here. &ndash;&gt;-->
<!--      </div>-->

<!--      &lt;!&ndash; Used to display form errors. &ndash;&gt;-->
<!--      <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>-->
<!--    </div>-->

<!--    <b-button class="space" id="payment-request-button">Submit Payment</b-button>-->
<!--  </form>-->


    <b-button class="space" type="submit" >Submit Payment</b-button>
  </form>
</template>
```

Javascript for submitting form.

```
let form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
  form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
    console.log(event);
    event.preventDefault();

    stripe.createToken(card).then(function (result) {
      if (result.error) {
        // Inform the user if there was an error.
        let errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
        errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
      } else {
        // Send the token to your server.
        stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
        return result.token
      }
    }).then(function (result) {
      console.log(result);
      axios({
        method: "POST",
        url: '/api/checkout',
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${authService.idToken}`,
        },
        data: {
          subscription: result.id,
          plan: this.plan
        },
      }).then(function (res) {
        // alert("It went through! How? ")
      }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err)
      });
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you'd like to pass additional field data to Stripe so that the card billing address info and other data available in the form is populated.

The `createToken` method that you're calling in the form submit handler can take two arguments: the card element and an optional argument containing the tokenData. https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference#stripe-create-token

You could manually refer to your form elements and pass them as `tokenData` like this:

```js
var address1Input = document.getElementById('address_line1');
var addressCityInput = document.getElementById('address_city');
var stateInput = document.getElementById('state');
var nameInput = document.getElementById('name');

var tokenData = {
  address_line1: address1Input.value,
  address_city: addressCityInput.value,
  address_state: stateInput.value,
  name: nameInput.value
};
stripe.createToken(card, tokenData).then(function (result) {
  //...
```

Comment: Ok so I have to do it manually? It appears as if they are expecting certain elements and I thought they would be looking for certain Id's that are standard in payments. The object I posted from the `console.log` were there prior to me changing my `id`s and `name`s.

Comment: Yes, this piece is manual. You have to pass these data as the second argument to `createToken`